# I am trying to program Arduino UNO light-up 4 Leds using C sharp code

Tags: c#, arduino

I have Arduino UNO, Bread Board, resistors, LEDs and jumper wires.

I am able to light on/off only 1 LED from my C# program. How can I set inputs to all leds to turn on/off all leds at same time through C# code?

```
int ledPin[] = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}; 
void setup() 
{ 
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    for (int i =0;i<8;i++) 
    {
        pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT); 
    }
} 

void loop()
{
    String st="11111111"; 
    for(int ch=0;ch < st.length();ch++)
    { 
        if(st.charAt(ch)=='1') 
        { 
            digitalWrite(ledPin[ch],1);
        } 
        else
        { 
            digitalWrite(ledPin[ch],0);
        }
    }
}
```

[Picture of my layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFkMc.jpg)

Comment: What is the implementation of digitalWrite?

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving out too much required info.
What does your arduino sketch look like?
What does your c# program look like?
And what does your circuit look like?

As simple as your question is relative to each of these 3 disciplines, your question is impossible to answer as is, and would probably be put on hold if reviewed by a moderator familiar in any two...

Add some info and then we can get into the exact transport mechanism you using to send data from whatever device it is running your c# program, to which import peripheral you are using to read it on your uno board...

Comment: int ledPin[] = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

Comment: My sketch looks like this::::

int ledPin[] = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};              

                  void setup() {
                     Serial.begin(9600);
                     for (int i =0;i<8;i++)
                    {pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT); }}

void loop() {String st="11111111";
      for(int ch=0;ch < st.length();ch++){
      if(st.charAt(ch)=='1') {
      digitalWrite(ledPin[ch],1);}
      else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin[ch],0);}}}

Comment: I have added an circuit imagein question above

Comment: first off its better to add code to your original question than a comment.

Comment: anyway, a quick glance, it seems even if your code was correct, you need to insert a delay between each on/off transition, at the end of each loop that is, so you can see the change.  Meaning by default your code is executing way too fast to perceive a change let alone give the led enough time to turn on.

Comment: also, it seems that your logic needs to be inverted, it looks like if you find the port high, your setting it high again.   And inversely

Comment: The String value can be any binary value.
Inside the loop what I am doing is I am reading each char and checking if it is '0' or '1'.
If it is '1', then I am setting LED of that position to HIGH.
If it is '0' then I am setting LED of that position to LOW